# solve this error message of unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

everyone and thanks in advance for any help that I receive. I am trying this program that looks for emails and phone numbers using regular expressions and I come across this error message that seems simple but I have tried everything to sort it out but it just doesn't seem to be working the error message states (unexpected character after line continuation character) now I have tried doubling up on my backlashes but it still returns the same error can u help me in solving this error message here is the code

```
# TODO: COPY RESULTS TO THE CLIPBOARD
if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('copied to clipboard:')
    print(\'\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('no phone numbers or email addresses found.')
```

Comment: You have a backslash in your second `print` that doesn't belong.

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the backslash ( \ ):

This:

```
print(\'\n'.join(matches))
```

Should be:

```
print('\n'.join(matches))
```